# how to test firebase cloud function express webserver changes locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am writing an express webserver using Firebase. However, it seems that I can't test my changes locally.

I am attempting to follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) for testing cloud functions locally. But when I make changes locally, only the deployed version gets executed, not the local version.

In two separate shells, I am running:

`firebase emulators:start --only functions`
and
`firebase serve --only hosting`

Here is `/functions/index.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
app.use(cors);

app.get('/myroute', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('hello1');
});

module.exports = {
    app: functions.https.onRequest(app),
};
```

When I modify 'hello1' to 'hello2', then save, restart both servers, and request `localhost:5000/myroute` in my browser, it still responds with `hello1`.

How can I get my local cloud function changes to appear when I request `localhost:5000/myroute`?

Comment: *"only the deployed version gets executed, not the local version"* - this doesn't make sense to me, since what you're describing here doesn't run a `firebase deploy` command.  How can your deployed version change if you haven't actually deployed the new code?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in the question. After creating `myroute` which returns 'hello1', I ran `firebase deploy`. Then I changed `myroute` to return 'hello2', and ran the local emulator and server, and visited `localhost:5000/myroute`, but it still returns 'hello1'. I expected `localhost:5000/myroute` to return 'hello2'